# Excel is missing certain functions

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Just now i realized that my Excel Version is missing some functions, e.g. =UNIQUE() or =XLOOKUP(). Also in the tab with the list of all functions these are not available. Other functions work fine though. Is there a way to install these functions manually?

I am using: Microsoft® Excel® 2016 MSO (Version 2112 Build 16.0.14729.20156) 64 Bit

I just tried to update, but it is already up-to-date.

[Sidenote: I am using the German Version, so I am actually missing the functions =EINDEUTIG() and =XVERWEIS() but either or - these functions are missing in my Excel]

Comment: Nup, you need to upgrade to a new version or write your own logic in VBA.

Comment: `UNIQUE()` and `XLOOKUP()` only available to ***Microsoft-365***.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you're using Microsoft Office 365 compatible version of Excel, your only other chance might be to sign up with Office Insider, which gives you access to exclusive new content / features as a trial user (whilst `unique`, `filter`, `let`, `sort`, `sortby` etc. functionality has been out for some time, there may well be dependencies on this RE: new content). Thanks to Insider I had access to unique functionality long before the Office 365 build was officially launched (about a year before if I remember correctly).

You can do both this and see what version Excel you are on by opening Excel and selecting File -> Account:

[image: Office a/c info and Insider details]